# What are same *hidden* useful bits of information you can get from the client in Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm wondering whether you can get the client's machine name. I guess you cannot.

Its interesting what you can get in the [System.Windows.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application_members%28VS.95%29.aspx) namespace.

I guess hidden is not the right word, more like "less-used" or unknowns. For example I use the one below to get the current URL

```
var hostName = Application.Current.Host.Source.Host;
```

I'd love to see what other devs out there are getting and using.

Thanks

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031450/are-there-any-undocumented-features-in-silverlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't acquire the client's machine name.  Silverlight doesn't allow you to get to any such data.  There is nothing about the client environment that you find out through silverlight that you can't already find from the browsers `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very broad question, but one class that you might be interested in is [System.Windows.Analytics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.analytics_members%28VS.95%29.aspx) which can be used to get performance related information from the Client.

Also HtmlPage.BrowserInformation returns a [BrowserInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.browserinformation%28VS.95%29.aspx) instance which contains data about the client's browser (really a managed wrapper for some javascript functions).